# Jquery slider whitespace between images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I created this Jquery slider but there is white space between the first image and the second, and between the 2nd and the third. I would like to stick the images to eachother when sliding. In what way do I have to change this code?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Jquery Slider </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .slider{
        width: 800px;
        height: 350px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 30px auto;
        font-size: 0px;

    }
    .slider img{
        width: 800px;
        height: 350px;

    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Slider(){
            $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
            $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

            var sc = $(".slider img").size();
            var count = 2;

            setInterval(function(){
            $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"}, 500);
            $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:"left"}, 500);
                if(count === sc){
                count = 1;
            }else{
                count = count + 1;
            }
            }, 6500);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Slider();">
        <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2009/07/22/109588/small.jpg" alt="leaf"></img>
        <img id="2" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2011/05/31/124348/small.jpg" alt="path"></img>
        <img id="3" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2013/12/30/152291/featured.jpg" alt="rice field"></img>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove the whitespace between the image tags.

Answer (score 0):

IMG tags are 'inline' elements: just like some piece of text, that's why whitespaces between them are displayed. You can use this kind of code which remains readable :

```
<body onload="Slider();">
   <div class="slider">
       <img id="1" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2009/07/22/109588/small.jpg" alt="leaf"></img
      ><img id="2" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2011/05/31/124348/small.jpg" alt="path"></img
      ><img id="3" src="http://www.stockvault.net/data/2013/12/30/152291/featured.jpg" alt="rice field"></img>
   </div>
</body>
```